# Parallel ForEach slow performance

Tags: c#

Im trying to copy some photos from a remote path to local.
I check if photo exist then i write the product in a text file.
Im newbie with Parallel stuff
I try but it takes several minute with 6000 products and 12000 photos

```
private async void button4_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new MyEntities();
        var articoli = context.Articoli.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(...)
            .OrderByDescending(...)
            .ThenBy(...)
            .ToList();

        var paths = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        int countFotoSmall = 0;

        Parallel.ForEach(articoli, (articolo) =>
         {
             count++;
             if (FotoExists($"{articolo.Codart}Small.jpg"))
             {
                 paths.AppendLine(@"""/assets/items/" + articolo.Codart + @"Small.jpg"",");
                 countFotoSmall++;
             }
         });

        using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:.../fotoSmallSW.txt"))
        {
            await file.WriteAsync(paths.ToString());
        }

        MessageBox.Show($"End successfully: articoli {count}, items Small.jpg {countFotoSmall}");
    }

    private bool FotoExists(string fotoSmall)
    {
        var fotoWeb = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\remote path...");
        bool exists = false;

        Parallel.ForEach(fotoWeb, foto =>
        {
            if (foto.Substring(foto.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) == fotoSmall)
                exists = true;
        });

        return exists;
    }
```

What i wrong ? How can improve time complexity?

Comment: Perhaps you could drop the string builder and go for a  `ConcurrentBag<string>();`.

Comment: Not about performance but correctness - you are modifying concurrently `count++` and `countFotoSmall++` without any synchronization, use `Interlocked.Increment`. And the same goes to `StringBuilder`

Comment: Wonder if the performance of `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path + fotoSmall)` is better or worse than `File.Exists(path + fotoSmall)`. Could you try calling `File.Exists` instead?

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is pointless. You don't need to know all of the files in the folder. **Look for the specific one you are interested in** with `File.Exists`.

Comment: Your `private bool FotoExists()`, does it do anything other than [`File.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-3.1)? Or [does it not](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793)?

Comment: You could probaly cache the Directory.EnumerateFiles. So you don't look for all file again and again

Comment: `I check if photo exist then i copy.` Where is the copy logic? Could you call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_ (which will succeed only if the file isn't already there)?

Comment: I see no use of the count, perhaps it simply boil down to `var fileExists = myArticlesPaths    .AsParallel()
    .Where .Select`

Comment: Copying 12.000 images takes several minutes... so? Copy them manually and tell us how long it took please ;)

Comment: If it took 10msec a photo to transfer 6000 photos would take a minute and 12000 two minutes.  How may bytes are each photo?

Comment: about 4 kb at photo

Comment: I try with File.Exists and Interlocked.Increment for count varibles and it works better then earlier. tks everybody

Answer (score 2):

Ciao, your code has many threading errors. Lets talk about **Shared resources**:

```
    var paths = new StringBuilder(); //this is a shared resuorces
    int count = 0; //this is a shared resuorces
    int countFotoSmall = 0; //this is a shared resuorces
   Parallel.ForEach(articoli, (articolo) =>
   {
     count++;
     if (FotoExists($"{articolo.Codart}Small.jpg"))
     {
         paths.AppendLine(@"""/assets/items/" + articolo.Codart + @"Small.jpg"",");
         countFotoSmall++;
     }
   });
```

All the variables outside `Parallel` are called `shared`. This means that if you want to use them in `Parallel` you need a `lock` statement:

```
var paths = new StringBuilder(); 
object lockpaths = new object();
int count = 0; 
object lockcount = new object();
int countFotoSmall = 0;
object lockcountFotoSmall  = new object();
Parallel.ForEach(articoli, (articolo) =>
{
  lock (lockcount) count++;
  if (FotoExists($"{articolo.Codart}Small.jpg"))
  {
     lock (lockpaths) paths.AppendLine(@"""/assets/items/" + articolo.Codart + @"Small.jpg"",");
     lock (countFotoSmall) countFotoSmall++;
  }
});
```

`lock` means that one thread for each time can takes a shared variable and use it. Otherwise result could be totally unpredictable!
As you can see, you `Parallel` is quite useless bacause almost all the code must be done in `lock` (sequentially). My opinion is to remove this `Parallel` and to put a normal `for`.

Also this one:

```
Parallel.ForEach(fotoWeb, foto =>
{
   if (foto.Substring(foto.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) == fotoSmall)
   exists = true; //shared variable. Not good...
});
```

is not good. My opinion is to remove this `Parallel`.

So how increase performances? Tryo to modify your code like this:

```
private async void button4_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new MyEntities();
        var articoli = context.Articoli.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(...)
            .OrderByDescending(...)
            .ThenBy(...)
            .ToList();

        var paths = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        int countFotoSmall = 0;
        var fotoWeb = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\remote path...");

        foreach(var articolo in articoli) {
            count++;
            if (FotoExists($"{articolo.Codart}Small.jpg", fotoWeb)) {
                 paths.AppendLine(@"""/assets/items/" + articolo.Codart + @"Small.jpg"",");
                 countFotoSmall++;
            }
        }

        using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:.../fotoSmallSW.txt"))
        {
            await file.WriteAsync(paths.ToString());
        }

        MessageBox.Show($"End successfully: articoli {count}, items Small.jpg {countFotoSmall}");
    }

    private bool FotoExists(string fotoSmall, IEnumerable fotoWeb)
    {
        bool exists = false;

        foreach(string foto in fotoWeb) {
           if (foto.Substring(foto.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) == fotoSmall){
               exists = true;
               break;
           }    
        }
        return exists;
    }
```

What I have done differently from you? 3 things:

1. Calculate `fotoWeb` one time and not for each iteration;
2. Use `break;` in for to exit as soon as `exists` is set to true;
3. Remove `Parallel` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Based on all suggests i end up with that code...and works very well
Howere if any mistakes are found please notify me
tks everyone

```
private async void button4_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = new MyEntities();
            var articoli = context.Articoli.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(...)
                .OrderByDescending(...)
                .ToList();

            var paths = new StringBuilder();
            int count = 0;
            int countFotoSmall = 0;

            Parallel.ForEach(articoli, (articolo) =>
             {
                 Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

                 if (FotoExists($"{articolo.Codart}Small.jpg"))
                 {
                     lock (paths)
                     {
                         paths.AppendLine(@"""/assets/items/" + articolo.Codart + @"Small.jpg"",");
                     }

                     Interlocked.Increment(ref countFotoSmall);
                 }

             });

            using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\...\fotoSmallSW.txt"))
            {
                await file.WriteAsync(paths.ToString());
            }

            MessageBox.Show($"End successfully: articoli {count}, items Small.jpg {countFotoSmall}");
        }

        private bool FotoExists(string fotoSmall)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"\\path\" + fotoSmall))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: in a server folder

Comment: Ok, have you tried my solution? I'm quite curious to undestand if in this case a foreach is better than a Parallel strongly interlocked. Let me know :)

Comment: not yet but tomorrow i let you know...now im doing another thing

Comment: No rush, it's just a curiosity. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I will do it. Tks so much. Nice day you too. ;)

Comment: Personally I would use `ConcurrentBag`  + `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ...)` instead of locking on `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Hi Giovanni, Your solution is good because as you said Parallel execution for one operation is not so good. But FotoExists is slow because as other said iterate the entire folder so File.Exists is better